# new Youtube api for android: getting video title

Tags: android, api, youtube

I am using the new Youtube API for android. I have managed to use the API to display a particular playlist(using ListView) and upon clicking on a video on a list I am able to play that particular video.

My question is this. How can I get the details for a particular video? Details such as video title and the number of views. I have tried looking in YoutubeThumbnailView/loader, YoutubePlayerView, YoutubePlayer but no luck.

here is the code for the main activity let me know if you need further info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener{


private final static String PLAY_LIST_ID = "XXX";
private final static String DEV_KEY = "XXX";

private YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
private YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, YouTubeVideo>> arrayList;
private ListView listView;
private SpecialAdapter adapter;
private int counter;
private YouTubePlayerView playerView;
private YouTubePlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] keys = new String[]{"key"};
    int[] values = new int[]{R.id.imageView1};  
    arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, YouTubeVideo>>();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new onListClickListener());
    playerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player);
    thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(this);
    thumbnailView.initialize(DEV_KEY, this);
    playerView.initialize(DEV_KEY, this);
    adapter = new SpecialAdapter(this, arrayList, R.layout.row_layout, keys, values);
}


class onListClickListener implements OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player.cueVideo(arrayList.get(arg2).get("key").videoID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader arg1) {
    loader = arg1;
    loader.setPlaylist(PLAY_LIST_ID);
    loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String videoId) {
            HashMap<String, YouTubeVideo> map;
            ImageView imageView;

            if(loader.hasNext()){
                map = new HashMap<String, YouTubeVideo>();
                imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(arg0.getDrawable());
                map.put("key", new YouTubeVideo(imageView, videoId));
                arrayList.add(map);
                loader.next();
            }else {
                map = new HashMap<String, YouTubeVideo>();
                imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(arg0.getDrawable());
                map.put("key", new YouTubeVideo(imageView, videoId));
                arrayList.add(map);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
          boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player = player;
}

@Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    if(loader != null) {
        loader.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

}

Comment: How are you displaying a playlist ? can you post some code ? You must be getting an XML or JSON response.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong API. You should be using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api) then parsing the XML/Json. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12157379/420015)

Comment: am using the new experimental API that has been published by google/Youtube, here is the link to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: Does that mean that i can only use Google Data API to get Video title ?

Comment: Yes, you can only get video data with the Data API. The Android API is only for playback purposes, wish it was more advanced myself.

Comment: it seems that way, am i also correct in that the new Youtube Data API v3 requires and Access Token as well as the DEV KEY to get titles of videos given IDs ?